# how to install postgresql on Linux

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Linux and have been using KDE for a little while.  I'm working on learning more ruby on rails.  The book I'm reading uses postgresql but I cannot find a walkthrough of installing postgresql on KDE.  On this page - https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg10 - it doesn't list an rpm for KDE so I'm not sure if there's another one I can use or not.  I don't know enough about Linux/KDE yet to know.  Does anyone know if I can use any of the packages on that page or if there's another way to install postgresql on KDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So KDE is your desktop. It could be used on almost any operating system, and probably doesn't determine your install. It's more about distros/OS that you're on.  So, what OS are you on? Wild guess Fedora or Ubuntu.  Here are the install guides for each:

Fedora: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PostgreSQL

Ubuntu: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Neither is as bad as it seems. Just take them step by step.

BTW, in the Linux world the command line is king. At first, this will seem daunting, but after a while, you'll find it faster for many things. Maybe [Learn Enough Command Line to Be Dangerous](https://www.learnenough.com/command-line-tutorial) would help.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I don't know what the OS is then.  I thought it as KDE.  I just downloaded the KDE neon iso and installed from there.  I wasn't aware that there was an underlying OS.  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: I'm thinking it's fedora as sudo dnf install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib asks me for my password and attempts to work.  However I get the error message - here are no enabled repos.  Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.  When I run that command I get repolist: 0.  Sounds like something is screwed up?

Comment: What happens when you type (no sudo needed) cat /etc/issue?

Comment: Kde neon is ubuntu, I think.  What happens when you type "sudo apt update" If you get a bunch of listings of repos it's hitting, it is probably at least using apt.  BTW, you can find out more about neon here: https://neon.kde.org/faq

Comment: ah yes, must be ubuntu.  sudo apt update runs a bunch of updates.  thanks!

Comment: You should probably update your system if you just installed.  Also, why Neon?

Comment: What should I update? I mean I run the system updates... is there something  else you're referring to?  As for why neon, I had tried ubuntu in the past but recently saw neon on a friends computer and liked the UI.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So I don't think that KDE Neon is all that clearly documented, but it seems to me that if it's based on Ubuntu, you should be able to update your system with 'sudo apt update', and 'sudo apt upgrade'.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure I knew what you were referring to. Yes sudo apt update works fine.

Comment: You need the 'sudo apt upgrade' do actually run the upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

> Simple solution

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib

sudo -i -u postgres

psql
```